# How to customize an apa format in biblatex with bibtex as backend

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, apa-style

Since I'm using Texpad to do my writing, I have to use bibtex as backend when I use biblatex. However, bibtex does not support apa style. I cannot use the apa-style provided by biblatex. I am curious how I can customize my bibliography format as apa style when I use biblatex with bibtex as backend? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It depends a lot on how conforming you need your APA style to be. That term often refers to a generic author/year style, so you may be able to get by with using and adapting the basic `authoryear` style. But increasingly all `biblatex` styles assume `biber` so you may still encounter things you can't do. Alternatively, you could use the `apacite` package which uses `bibtex` and produces conforming APA6 (but not 7) citations. That's probably a simpler choice.

Comment: See [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812) for a complete example using `apacite`.

Comment: Thank you so much Alan!